# Best html5 resources - web and print

Tags: html

What are currently the best resources for learning html5 - I'm thinking web and books, particularly what's the best book

Comment: You may want to take a look at my more recent [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399016/html5-where-to-start/7399075#7399075).

Answer (score 10):

I think will be good resource to start with: http://slides.html5rocks.com/#slide1

Answer (score 7):

check

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/

Comment: +1 If you don't know/understand what html5 is it is the best starting point. Once you understand html5, boilerplate comes really handy!

Answer (score 4):

Its really not a learning site but it has a good and well documentet boilerplate. And in my opinion its really good to have especially when your starting out doing html5. You don't need to use it but its really handy as a reference. [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html5) and its [external links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html5#External_links). I'm not kidding; the article is the *best* resource on the web.

There aren't good HTML5 books on the market at this moment. You should just read the wikipedia article and walk through each link in the "External Links" section.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in similar question.

[Head First HTML5 Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449390544) is by far the best book I have ever seen for newbie front-end developer. It goes on to introduce Javascript for foundation. Then it shows all the magic combining HTML5 and Javascript.

(It is also good book if one wants to move ahead and learn some JS libraries like jQuery, dojo, prototype etc.)